# Setting a NamespacePrefixMapper for a Marshaller in Spring

Tags: spring, properties, javabeans

I created a pool of marshallers according to this article:

http://axixmiqui.wordpress.com/2009/09/01/spring-injecting-jaxb-unmarshaller/

I have a NamespacePrefixMapper also defined in Spring and I'd like to set the property when the Marshaller gets instantiated, but I can't seem to be able to do it.  Everytime I try to set the property Netbeans freaks out and crashes with an out of memory error even though I have plenty of memory available.

Here is my Marshaller bean:

```
<bean id="restMarshallerTarget" class="javax.xml.bind.Marshaller" 
        factory-bean="jaxbContext" factory-method="createMarshaller" scope="prototype">
    </bean>
```

The bean name for my mapper is "namespaceMapper".  I've tried adding:

```
<property name="com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper" value="namespaceMapper" />
```

,

```
<property name="com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper" ref="namespaceMapper" />
```

,
and

```
<property name="com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper"><ref bean="namespaceMapper"/></property>
```

No matter how I try to add the mapper, I start getting the exceptions... What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

Here is one of the exceptions:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restMarshallerTarget' defined in class path resource [context/spring-ws-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper' of bean class [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl]: Nested property in path 'com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper' does not exist; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'com' of bean class [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl]: Bean property 'com' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

This is how I previously set the mapper in code:

marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", namespaceMapper);

Comment: What exception are you seeing?

Comment: Beyond the out of memory errors, I just saw this one: